# Query for finding records where count is only 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named discounts. Within this table I have a account number, discount number, a discount status, a discount start and discount end date. I would like to find all records for account numbers with count of discount as 1 and that discount has end dates not equal to zero.

This is how the table looks like:

```
| account no        | discount no | status   |  end date |
|       14188971    |        111  | 1        | 12-DEC-23 | 
|       14188971    |        111  | 1        |      0    |
|       16743289    |        111  | 1        |      0    |
|       19908543    |        111  | 1        | 14-DEC-23 |
|       2510987     |        111  | 1        | 14-DEC-23 |
|       1663890     |        111  | 1        |      0    |
|       9033175     |        111  | 1        |      0    |
```

The result should look similar to this:

```
| account no        | end date  |
|       19908543    | 14-DEC-23 |
|       2510987     | 14-DEC-23 |
```

Query should exclude accounts with duplicate end dates such as 14188971 which have 2 entries, one of which has end date zero.

### I tried the below

```
select 
      account_no, 
      condition 
   from 
      ( select 
              at.account_no, 
              case when count( case when d.discount_no = '111' 
                                    and d.status = 1 then 1 end) = 1 
                   then 'One active Discount' end as condition
          from
             discounts d
                right join account_t at
                   on at.id = d.account_no
          where 
                 at.account_no in ('14188971','16743289', '19908543', '2510987','1663890','9033175')
             and pt.purchase_end_t <> 0
          group by 
             at.account_no )
   where 
      condition = 'One active Discount'
```

Expecting query to return just accounts with end dates not equal to zero excluding duplicates which have may have end dates not equal to zero.

Comment: Look at the `having` clause.

Comment: There is conflict between your result and your required result. You asked `that discount has end dates not equal to zero` , but all your result sets has `0` as `end date` . Could you please clarify your logic?

Comment: @RahidZeynalov You're right. I've edited the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the account number and end date, you can simply use GROUP BY with HAVING:

```
select account_no,
       MAX(end_date) end_date
  from table
 GROUP BY account_no
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    AND MAX(end_date) IS NOT NULL -- or != 0, or whatever...
```

If you need other columns, however, you can use windowing functions:

```
select *
  from (
    select col1,col2,col3,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY account_no) cnt,
           MAX(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY account_no) end_date
      from table
) where cnt = 1 and end_date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If `count(1) = 1` I think we don't need `max(end_date) in having` instead we need to add `where end_date is not null or what ever`

Comment: @RahidZeynalov `where ...` will filter out rows before aggregation, so you will not be able to identify actual number of rows per `account_no`. The answer is perfectly complete

Comment: This answer perfectly works for my scenario above. Thanks @paul-w

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get your result by following query:

```
    select accounts.* from accounts inner join (select account_no, count(end_date) as end_date from discounts where status = 1 and end_date != 0 group by account_no) as dis ON dis.account_no = accounts.id
```